# Get a value by scheme where index type is used before

Tags: typescript, generics

I have a class, which gets a configuration object. I want to be able to get and set values in it, by a method the class exposes.

```
type ConfigValue = {name: string, value: string};
type Schema = {
    [key: string]: {
        someValue: boolean,
        values: ConfigValue[]
    }
}

class Config {
    constructor(private config: Schema) { }

    public getValue(key: string): ConfigValue {
        // ...
    }

    public setValue(c: ConfigValue): void {
        // ...
    }
}
Now I create an instance of Config and pass the configuration:
const conf: Schema = {
    'general': {
        someValue: true,
        values: [
            { 'name': 'title', 'value': 'Title' },
            { 'name': 'charset', 'value': 'utf-8' }
        ]
    },
    'http': {
        someValue: boolean,
        values: [
            { 'name': 'proxy', 'value': 'http://proxy' }
        ]
    }
}

const c = new Config(conf);
c.getValue('proxy');
c.setValue('title', 'New Title');
```

Implementing this should work, but when implementing both methods I came across a problem: I can iterate over every object in Schema and afterwards, iterate over the values array. But it would be much easier, if I somehow could get the key. I thought of generics, passing the Scheme directly to the class, that both methods can use it, but I’m stuck at the method type definition now. I first thought about this:

```
class Config<T extends Schema> {
    constructor(private config: T) { }

    public getValue<K extends keyof T>(key: K): T[K]['values'] {
        return this.config[key].values;
    }
    …
}
```

K is now of type string | number (since index-type), and my return type is of T[K][‘values’], the Array of ConfigValues. But my goal was, that key is an actually ConfigValue.name property. My return type should also be of type ConfigValue.

```
public getValue<K extends keyof T>(key: string): T[K]['values'][??] {
    return this.config[??].values[key];
}
```

I have no idea if this is intended or not, nor if I should directly type a key in the definition (T[K]-->['groups']<--). Hope this is not to confusing, any help or ideas appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a mess in TypeScript types and JavaScript objects. Keep in mind that TypeScript is transpiled to pure JavaScript. So no types will exist during program execution. TypeScript works only during compilation and vanished during execution. So there is no way to use TypeScrpt types or generics to extract some data or to write any conditions. Types only usefull for checking if you passing argument of correct type to some function.

As array are dynamic in nature (you can add/remove elements during run time), there is no way to type check array contents. You cannot relay on TypeScript to find array element based on type.

If you want `ConfigValue.name` to be the key you should firstly refactor `Schema`. Now `Schema` contains array of `ConfigValue`. You have no way to extract single element of array except iterating over array. If possible, store configuration as object not as array.

Convertion to Object is possible only if `name` property is unique in array of values.

For example

```
type Schema = {
    [key: string]: {
        someValue: boolean,
        values: { [name: string]: ConfigValue }
    }
}
```

Now `getValue` can look like

```
public getValue(key: string): ConfigValue {
    let configItem = Object.keys(this.config).find(k => this.config[k].values[key] !== undefined);
    return configItem.values[key];
}
```

It's still required to iterate over `config` keys as by requirement you want to pass `ConfigValue.name` as key.